# SQL Insert Count of Distinct Values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently struggling with the following query. I've a table in a database with a list of companies and a number of products they have. I'm looking to *Count* the number of *unique products* they have and insert it into the row on the table where their company name is.

I've tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO table name
SET number of products =
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productName) FROM table name
GROUP BY company name
```

It's a single table. Desired output is:

```
CompanyName | Product | NumberOfProducts
Company A.    A.        3
Company A.    B.        3
Company A.    C.        3
```

Comment: if `product name` is a column's name with *space* in it use `DISTINCT [product name]`

Comment: What is the result you are having with that INSERT statement?

Comment: Hmmm. . . Do you have one table or two?  Can you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: Something is missing from your simplification of e the query I think.  Is there two tables involved (one that holds the products and one that holds the company name)? Can you show a schema so we can make the right query?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want an update:

```
UPDATE t
    SET numberofproducts = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT productname)
                            FROM tablename t2
                            WHERE t2.companyname = t.companyname
                           )
    FROM tablename t;
```

This query will update all rows in the table with the number of distinct products for that company.

Comment: It's a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is like this

```
company_name |  product_name   | number_of_products
----------------------------------------------------
foo          | wand            | null 
foo          | wand            | null
bar          | plug            | null
bar          | stick           | null
bar          | broom           | null
```

then

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select company_name, COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) as number_of_products 
    from table_name
    group by company_name
)
update t SET
   number_of_products = cte.number_of_products 
from table_name t
inner join CTE 
   on t.company_name = cte.company_name
```

will give you

```
company_name |  product_name   | number_of_products
----------------------------------------------------
foo          | wand            | 1 
foo          | wand            | 1
bar          | plug            | 3
bar          | stick           | 3
bar          | broom           | 3
```

Test: http://rextester.com/XWMYK90685

if you are looking to exclude a list of products from the count then change the CTE to

```
select company_name, COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) as number_of_products 
from table_name
where product_name not in ('stick')
group by company_name
```

although depending on how many exclusions you have you might want to do something like

```
declare @exclusions table
(
 product_name varchar(10) not null
)

insert into @exclusions (product_name) VALUES ('stick')
....
select company_name, COUNT(DISTINCT product_name) as number_of_products 
from table_name
where product_name not in (select product_name from @exclusions)
group by company_name
```

which would give you

```
company_name |  product_name   | number_of_products
----------------------------------------------------
foo          | wand            | 1 
foo          | wand            | 1
bar          | plug            | 2
bar          | stick           | 2
bar          | broom           | 2
```

Test for exclusions: http://rextester.com/AYPGFQ42106

Comment: There's only one table.

Comment: yes, you are getting the count of the product_name in that table and then using it to go back and update that same table.

Comment: I added a rextest of it so you can run it and see what I mean

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much for your help! If I'm looking to exclude a product would that simply be a WHERE statement after GROUP BY COMPANY NAME to say Product <> 'Product'?

Comment: added exclusion queries