# COUNT from table in one dataset, and add it to a column in a table in a different dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run an SQL Query on GCP's AI Notebooks, using BigQuery. I want to count the number of distinct rows from a table in a separate dataset, and add it to a column in a table in a different dataset.

Not sure if this is possible. I seem to be struggling (relatively new to SQL). Here's the script and the error. I haven't found anything exactly equivalent. Code based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721103/sql-insert-count-of-distinct-values-from-another-column).

```
%%bigquery 
UPDATE `project-id.dataset1.table1` t 
    SET var1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT var2)
                            FROM `project-id.dataset2.other_table` t2
                            WHERE t2.id = t.id
                           )
    FROM `project-id.dataset1.table1` t;
```

This produces the error

```
ERROR:
 400 Alias t in the FROM clause was already defined as the UPDATE target at [6:5]
```

If I remove the final line, which appears a bit redundant to me, I get a different error

```
ERROR:
 400 UPDATE must have a WHERE clause at [1:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
update `project-id.dataset1.table1` t
set var1 = (
  select count(distinct var2)
  from `project-id.dataset2.other_table` t2
  where t2.id =t.id
)
where true;
```